# How to test Speech input in microsoft BOT?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, botframework

I have integrated Speech input api (Bing Speech API) in one of the BOTs (MS BOT framework-.net) I am working on, but not sure how to test if it is working or not. Does MS Bot emulator facilitate testing it with mic? or should I use any of the channels like skype to test it?
Plz assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have created a Skype bot using the record action as defined in https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/calling/#calling-conversation-object-model to record audio from the user, and then perform speech-to-text with the Bing speech recognition API after the recording has been completed using the soundfile.

```
      private async Task OnRecordCompleted(RecordOutcomeEvent recordOutcomeEvent)
    {      
      string s = string.Empty;
                 string path = string.Empty;
                  if (recordOutcomeEvent.RecordOutcome.Outcome = Outcome.Success)
                 {
                      var record = await recordOutcomeEvent.RecordedContent;
            path =               HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"~/{recordOutcomeEvent.RecordOutcome.Id}.wav");
            using (var writer = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await record.CopyToAsync(writer);
            }
            Attachment att = new Attachment()
            {
                ContentUrl = "file:///" + path,
                ContentType = "audio/wav",

            };
            s = DoSpeechReco(att);
```

Comment: Can you please look at this question and please guide, this seems similar to my problem ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704197/create-a-bot-that-can-record-voice-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

A number of the channels allow you to send audio files to your bot. If you enable your bot on Facebook Messenger, simply press the microphone icon to record audio

[image]

A player for the recorded audio will appear in the user's stream and an audio file be passed back to your bot as an attachment:

[image]